# How to use wifi router as PoE?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, power-supply, wireless-router

Is it possible to use wifi router as PoE?

This is a picture of my network connectivity.

[image]

My PoE is not working properly.

So I am thinking of connecting the Ethernet cable(which is the cable from outdoor CPE) directly to any one of the port of wifi router to supply power for the device.

As far of my knowledge, PoE is a device which supplies power to the device.

My question is "Does power can be supplied by the LAN port of wifi router?"

If it is possible, please tell me how to configure the wireless router to use as a PoE.

One main thing, wifi and other LAN ports should work properly.

Please help me out ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No that won't work.  PoE is specific to the device and will not "hop" through a switch/hub.  You can find injectors pretty cheap that will perform what you need just make sure you get the correct voltage for your device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to understand... But, I will take a shot:

POE is a complicated topic, to begin with, the picture you show actually shows ubiquity passive POE... This is incompatible with the normal POE.

To explain - Passive POE is a much cheaper method ([Read here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet#Passive)), as there is no negotiation with the device - if it is on, the POE injector is ALWAYS supplying power to the device.

Standard POE (802.3af) or POE+ (802.3at) on the other hand, actually have two way communication between the device giving the power and requiring it.

Now, for either method of POE, you have two choices to give power:

1. [Use a POE enabled switch](http://www.amazon.co.uk/D-Link-8-Port-Gigabit-Desktop-Switch/dp/B004FJSSTW), Router or other network infrastructure device.
2. [Use a POE Injector](http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-TL-PoE150S-Injector-Adapter-Compliant/dp/B001PS9E5I/ref=sr_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1420380639&sr=1-2&keywords=poe%20injector)

Then for the device itself, you need either:

1. A POE enabled device (A lot of business grade VOIP phones, CCTV, Wireless AP support this).
2. A POE Splitter:

[image]

A POE splitter is a nice trick I have used several times to power non POE equipment in locations where there is no power.

Just remember, don't mix passive/standard and if you go down the splitter route, make sure it has enough juice to power your device.

Comment: +1 & The key there is to make sure the injector provides enough power to the end device.

Answer (score 0):

> Does power can be supplied by the LAN port of wifi router?

No.
PoE requires approximately 45 VoltsDC to be sent over the UTP cable.  The typical wireless router uses a 12VDC supply, although using a DC-to-DC converter could be possible but not likely.  And that would require a power-supply larger than the typical 20-30W power adapter (e.g. 12V at 2.5A output).  Expect a PoE-capable switch or a PoE injector to use a power adapter of ~40W or more (e.g. 48VDC and at least 0.8 A output) (assuming it uses an external supply).